# Upgrading errors SP2007 Enterprise (MOSS) to SP2010 Foundation?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from SP2007 Enterprise edition to SP2010 Foundation. I am going attaching content database route. When I mount the content database to SP2010 and getting below errors. Do I need to ignore them or it may cause any errors?

We don't want any enterprise features.

```
INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: Found 1 web(s) using missing web template 7 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_80.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: The site definitions with Id 7 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_80], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if necessary.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: Found 2 web(s) using missing web template 20 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_80.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: The site definitions with Id 20 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_80], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if necessary.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80
 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: Found 1 web(s) using missing web template 34 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_80.
 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: The site definitions with Id 34 is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_80], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing site definition may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the site definition and restart upgrade if necessary.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: Found 1 web(s) using missing web template 39 (lcid: 1033) in ContentDatabase WSS_Content_80.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: Found a missing feature Id = [a392da98-270b-4e85-9769-04c0fde267aa]

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: The feature with Id a392da98-270b-4e85-9769-04c0fde267aa is referenced in the database [WSS_Content_80], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

 [INFO] [11/18/2014 10:46:46 AM]: SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content_80

 [ERROR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration from MOSS to SharePoint Foundation is not supported. The server or enterprise level features in MOSS may not be available in Foundation resulting in usability and performance issues.

- MOSS 2007 Standard SP2  >> SharePoint Server 2010 Standard
- MOSS 2007 Enterprise SP2  >> SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise

You can use the 3rd party tool to migrate from MOSS to 2010 i.e Metalogix, Sharegate. They offer free trial.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80a07897-db24-4313-bba9-4702f7dfaa77/migrating-moss-2007-sites-to-sharepoint-foundation-2010?forum=sharepointadminprevious